# Question about the exponential function.

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

For $x\in\mathbb R$ we define
$$\exp(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$
This is the standard definition of the exponential function, e.g. given by Rudin in the introduction to *Real and Complex Analysis*. It is well-known that this series converges absolutely for all real $x$, so this definition is perfectly acceptable.

I have a rather silly question though. How do we get
$$\exp(0)=1 $$
from this definition? It's clear if we use a different definition of $\exp$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac0n\right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1. $$
But how do we reconcile the expression of the form $0^0$ in
$$\exp(0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{0^n}{n!} $$

My thoughts: if $x\ne0$, then $x^0=1$, so $\lim_{x\to0}x^0=1$. Hence for any nonnegative integer $N$,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{x^n}{n!} = 1,$$
and so
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{x^n}{n!}=1. $$
It remains to show that the above is equal to
$$\exp(0) = \lim_{x\to0}\exp(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{x^n}{n!}. $$
Is the absolute convergence of $\exp(x)$ for $x\ne0$ and the uniform convergence of $\exp$ on any bounded subset of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ enough to justify the above interchange in limits? If so, post it as an answer, and I will accept it and put this admittedly pedantic question to rest.

Comment: $0^0$ is 1. I don't think this is troubling, but if it troubles you, note that $x^0=1$ for any $x\neq 0$, and extend $x\mapsto x^0$ to $x=0$ by imposing continuity.

Comment: I agree with your argument that $\lim_{x\to0}x^0=1$ (in fact I happened to prove that just now before reading your comment). But the statement $0^0=1$ definitely troubles me. For example, $0^x=0$ for any $x\ne0$, so $\lim_{x\to0}0^x = 0$...

Comment: @Math1000 I'm replying here becayse there's no need to flood Bernard's message box. Reply: That would be, in a loose sense, changing the definition of $\exp$ you're using. In spite of me preferring what you just suggested, what I actually said was that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right):=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$. This is OK because the LHS doesn't necessarily have another meaning, due to the $0^0$ problem. If yo''re OK with this, I can ponder posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard convention is that when you write $x^n$, then when $n = 0$, this is the constant function $1$, regardless of the value of $x$. This is what people always mean by $x^0$ in a power series $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n$. This is the unique convention, for example, that makes $x^0$ continuous from the right as a function of $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but this doesn't seem like a complete answer because clearly we want to define $\exp$ for $\mathbb R$, not just $\mathbb R_{\geqslant 0}$.

Comment: @Math1000: sure, and so we extend $x^0$ to be $1$ for all values of $x$. That's the value it should take for all $x \neq 0$ anyway.

Answer (score 3):

$\exp 0=1+ \dfrac 0{1!}+\dfrac{0^2}{2!}+\dots+\dfrac{0^n}{n!}+\dotsm$

Where is the problem?

Comment: Where did you get the $1$ from? Simply plugging in $0$ we would have $\frac{0^0}{0!}$ and $0^0$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: It is a pure convention: the formula, as such, is valid only for $x\in \mathbf C^*$. Don't forget the first term is equal to $1$, whatever the value of $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Well, Rudin says that "$e^0=\exp(0)=1$, by (1)" (where (1) is the formula given above). I don't see where that conclusion comes from. I agree that I am being a bit pedantic, but I just want to be rigorous here.

Comment: @Math1000 for $x=0$ the first term would be $0^0$. In this particular case this symbol, $0^0$, is just a convenient way of writing $1$. You don't prove it, it's a definition: $0^0:=1$. However I personally would rather think of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$ has an abbreviation of $1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$. I find it less ambiguous and more satisfying.

Comment: I agree that defining $\exp(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is less ambiguous. I am not comfortable with stating $0^0=1$ from the simple fact that $\lim_{x\to0}0^x=0$...

Comment: @Math1000 I'm not sure what $0^x$ even denotes. If $x$ is an non-null integer, there's no problem. But what about the other possibilities? In particular for $x$ irrational.

Comment: If $x$ is non-integer, the rigorous definition of $a^x$ requires the exponential function be defined. We only can give *heuristic* arguments for the convention $0^0=1$ here — in particular the function must be continuous at $0$.

Comment: @GitGud fair enough, let me make that more precise: $0^n=0$ for any positive integer $n$, so $0^{\frac1n}=0$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}0^{\frac1n}=0$.

Comment: @Math1000: Not sure you argument works: $x^{\frac 1n}$ requires the exponential function be defined first.

Comment: At Bernard: It can be defined as the unique real such that ...(details are obvious, depending on the eveness of $n$). @Math1000 OK, so you can't make that limit equal $1$, tough luck. There are reasons to defend both sides. In the end, since the notation is so convenient, $0^0:=1$ wins in this context.I'm not sure what you want. Not all notation is perfect, this is one such case.

Comment: I know it can be defined from the bijection theorem, but that doesn't explain easily why a restriction to positive numbers, even if $n$ is odd, and it doesn't give an easy way to compute it. The exponential way is much easier, once you have the basics on power series.

Comment: @GitGud Write the definition of $\exp(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ as an answer and I'll accept it. I think that is the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

By directly replacing $x$ by $0$ in the sum, the first term is indeterminate $(0^0)$. You have to expand the sum, and then you can evaluate at $x = 0$:

$$ \left.\exp(x)\right|_{x = 0} = \left.\left( 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \dots \right)\right|_{x = 0} = 1 + 0 + \frac{0^2}{2} + \frac{0^3}{3} + \dots = 1$$

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that $\lim_{x\to0}\exp(x)=1$? That is what I was trying to show, from the definition, but I got a little bogged down in the details.